# Numeric Keyboard

Tags: python, wxpython, real-time

I would like to design a numeric keyboard and I do not know which function to use to have real time display when I clicked a button, say 1 is displayed in the textctrl when the button 1 is clicked like a calculator display. And it can display like 1234 when 1234 buttons are clicked in series. And I wonder how can I add backspace, clear functions to that

```
import wx

class iCal(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Text")
        panel = MainPanel(self)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.frame = parent 

        text_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=float(num))

        button_0 = wx.Button(self, label="0")        
        button_1 = wx.Button(self, label="1")
        button_2 = wx.Button(self, label="2")

        button_0.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.output0)
        button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.output1)
        button_2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.output2)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(text_1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_0, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def self.output0(self,event):
        if float(num) > 0:
            num = num + str(0)

    def self.output1(self,event):
        num = num + str(1)

    def self.output1(self,event):
        num = num + str(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = iCal()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[Numberic Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3I9D.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import wx

class iCal(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Text")
        panel = MainPanel(self)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.frame = parent
        self.text_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="0")
        button_0 = wx.Button(self, label="0")
        button_1 = wx.Button(self, label="1")
        button_2 = wx.Button(self, label="2")
        clear = wx.Button(self, label="Clear")

        button_0.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.output0)
        button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.output1)
        button_2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.output2)
        clear.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN,self.clear)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.text_1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_0, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(clear, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def output0(self,event):
        num = "0"
        my_string = self.text_1.GetValue() + num
        self.text_1.SetValue(my_string)

    def output1(self,event):
        num = "1"
        my_string = self.text_1.GetValue() + num
        self.text_1.SetValue(my_string)

    def output2(self,event):
        num = "2"
        my_string = self.text_1.GetValue() + num
        self.text_1.SetValue(my_string)

    def clear(self,event):
        my_string = self.text_1.GetValue()
        my_string = my_string[:len(my_string)-1]
        self.text_1.SetValue(my_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = iCal()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

1. If you are going to post code, at least run it first to make sure that you aren't posting rubbish.
2. Read about manipulating strings before you post: [Strings](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realize I posted the wrong file, the files all have similar names, sorry about that. May you please tell me which is the best class to be used to design the UI which I posted after the codes. I need buttons like that and the 'enter' button is not a square. I just found GirdSizer and I wonder if there are better classes avaliable? Thank you very much.

Comment: Check out `wx.FlexGridSizer` as well

Comment: Thank you, I just found a tutorial on that.